# Change background color of Files-manager ubuntu 22.04

Tags: files, 22.04, desktop-background

Is there any way to change the background color (white) of Files-manager in ubuntu 22.04?
I tried tweak-tools and dconf-editor but did not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not as such possible to change the background color of the Files, the file manager "nautilus" of the default Ubuntu desktop. Its colors are determined by the current GTK theme in use, Yaru in case of the standard Ubuntu desktop.

You can switch to the dark system theme, which would render the chrome and background of all supported applications with a dark color. You could have only Files use a dark theme (or a different theme) with a command:

```
GTK_THEME=Yaru:dark nautilus
```

to have it use the dark variant of the Yaru theme.

To have nautilus launch with the dark theme by default, edit its launcher accordingly. To do so, copy the systemwide launcher (`/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`) to your local `~/.local/share/applications` directory. Prepend `env GTK_THEME=Yaru:dark` to each of the lines starting with `Exec=`, for example

```
Exec=env GTK_THEME=Yaru:dark nautilus --new-window %U
```

Comment: The command "GTK_THEME=Yaru:dark nautilus" did not change nautilus to dark mode. Eventually, I used Gnome-Tweak to select a dark theme for all applications, though it was not my choice.

Comment: It only does for the current instance. To implement that for your menu system, you need to edit the launcher for Files.

Comment: I have now added specific instructions on how to include this in the launcher.

Comment: Sorry to say that even the mentioned instruction added to launcher did not work for me. It seems that it is not easy to change the background color of nautilus easily in ubuntu 22.04. We are left with the specified themes in the Gnome-tweak tool.

Comment: It works for me on Ubuntu 22.04. I ran it a few days, but then I reverted - still prefer the light theme overall.